# ReRender Page using Anchor Tag

Tags: apex, css, html

How can I make the whole tab, using an anchor tag in `<li>` tag, be clickable and to render resultant page?

Code:

```
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li id="attendee" class="current">
            <a href="{!$Site.BaseUrl}/apex/BLN_QUICKREGISTRATION?id={!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}&tab=attendee">Self Service Quick Registration</a>
        </li>
        <li id="staffwithpayment">
            <a href="{!$Site.BaseUrl}/apex/BLN_QUICKREGISTRATION?id={!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}&tab=staffwithpayment">Staff Quick Registration With Payments</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css code::

```
<style>
#tabs-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -.7%;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 103%;
    background: #fefefe;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0, #f3f3f3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fefefe), color-stop(100%, #f3f3f3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0, #f3f3f3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0, #f3f3f3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0, #f3f3f3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0, #f3f3f3 100%);
}

.tabs-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    outline: none;
}

.tabs-menu li {
    position: relative;
    /* top: 1px; */
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    /* background-color: #DDD; */
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 11px 20px 9px 20px;
}

.tabs-menu li.current {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    /* height: 14.4px; */
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px #2a90d3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px #2a90d3;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px #2a90d3;
}

.tabs-menu li:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0, #dedede 100%);
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0, #dedede 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcfcfc), color-stop(100%, #dedede));
}

.tabs-menu li a {
    outline: none;
    focus: none;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs-menu .current a {
    outline: none;
    focus: none;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.tab {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

.tab-content {
    width: 660px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}

#tab-1 {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: You can add an onclick event listener to <li> directly and perform redirection when that event occurs.

Comment: Hi Azinq,I tried using onclick event listener for li tag,the page desired page is not rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're `<a>` is doing what you want to do, but if you click elsewhere in the `<li>` and not directly on the text, it's not taking you to the page you're specifying in the `href=""`?

Without knowing your Visualforce and CSS code, this is likely because if how the anchor tag fills the list tag. You can see this visually by inspecting the elements in a browser's developer tools.

This can be fixed by changing the CSS a little. If, for instance you've got CSS such as below:

```
.tabs-menu li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You should be able to get the `<a>` to "fill" it's parent, in this instance the `<li>` by getting the anchor tag to inherit it's parents width and height. This would do that:

```
.tabs-menu a {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The anchor tag will that take on it's parents dimensions.

Comment: Hi Poet,Thanks for reply. What you said above is exactly my requirement.

Comment: I tried to add css for that.But not getting desired result,i Dont know reason... i am sending the css what we used, can you change this as per the above requirement.

Comment: `padding: 4px 10px;` on `.tabs-menu li` might be causing a problem. You'll be pushing child elements inwards therefore your `<a>` wouldn't be able to cover the whole `<li>`.

Comment: Hi Poet Thanks for reply, I have removed that padding ,but also <a>tag not  able to cover the whole <li>.Let me know if any suggestions for alternatives for that....